# hadoop command to get latest sub directory name from a directory in hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop

How do I find the latest subdirectory created inside a directory in hadoop?
e.g in hadoop if i have directory called `mgm` which has 2 sub directories 1 and 2 as shown here:

```
/user/mgm/1
/user/mgm/2
```

I want to know which one out of 1 or 2 was created first.

```
hadoop fs -ls -t /user/mgm/ | head -1
```

is not working for me. It says `"illegal option -t"`

Comment: What version of hadoop do you have? The `-t` flag [is a valid option](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls)

Comment: Are you able to update your `hadoop` binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-t` option for `hdfs dfs -ls` is a new feature targeted to Apache Hadoop 2.8.0, which has not yet been released.  This is tracked in JIRA issue [HADOOP-8934](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8934).  I'm not sure why that option is visible in the [`ls`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls) documentation already.

Meanwhile, another option is to use the [`hdfs dfs -stat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat) command with a format string that includes modification time.  Here is an example demonstrating how we can use `hdfs dfs -stat` to identify `dir2` as the sub-directory with the latest modification time.

```
> hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/mgm/dir1

> hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/mgm/dir2

> hdfs dfs -ls /user/mgm
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - chris supergroup          0 2015-12-31 14:38 /user/mgm/dir1
drwxr-xr-x   - chris supergroup          0 2015-12-31 14:38 /user/mgm/dir2

> hdfs dfs -help stat
-stat [format] <path> ... :
  Print statistics about the file/directory at <path>
  in the specified format. Format accepts filesize in
  blocks (%b), type (%F), group name of owner (%g),
  name (%n), block size (%o), replication (%r), user name
  of owner (%u), modification date (%y, %Y).
  %y shows UTC date as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" and
  %Y shows milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.
  If the format is not specified, %y is used by default.

> hdfs dfs -stat '%y    %n' /user/mgm/*
2015-12-31 22:38:16    dir1
2015-12-31 22:38:19    dir2

> hdfs dfs -stat '%Y    %n' /user/mgm/*
1451601496198    dir1
1451601499150    dir2

> hdfs dfs -stat '%Y    %n' /user/mgm/* | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{ print $NF }'
dir2
```

> How do I find the latest subdirectory created inside a directory in hadoop?

Keep in mind that all of these features reference modification time, not creation time.  The modification time can be updated as the contents of a directory change.  If you really strictly need creation time, then watch out for this.  There is no option available for getting visibility of creation time as a value tracked separately from modification time.

Comment: @Monica, I'm glad to hear it!  :-)  If this was helpful, then please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Had exact same problem, solved my case using your final command. 
Thanks a bunch!